# Resizing a datatable based on the clients screen size

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, datatable

I have a barcode scanner application that was built in visual studio 2008, .net compact using c#.

We are testing the software on multiple devices, MC9090 and MC9190

MC9090 - 96 DPI , 250 screen size
MC9190 - 192 DPI , 460 screen size  (approximately)

The application is built for the MC9090 and now I am testing it on MC9190 but have not written the code for the application - that developer has left

As a result of this the datatable that is being built dynamically is too small in the MC9190

I have fixed the background image on the form to resize according to the DPI of the device by changing the sizemode property of the picturebox  to  StretchImage

Is there a way of doing this for Datatables that are built dynamically ?

I have a barcode sample program called cs_barcode2Sample1 running on both devices successfully but unfortunately I dont have the .sln for this and dont know where to get it

Any Help would be appreciated. 
Rachael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by finding out what the dpi of the device is and setting the X and Y values

```
       using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
           {
               float dpiX = g.DpiX;
               float dpiY = g.DpiY;
            }
```

Then based on that I perform a simple calculation that will resize the device by setting its width and height
So the standard DPI is 96 so I divided the device DPI by 96

```
        private static int dpiwidth = (int)(dpiX / 96);
        private static int dpiheight = (int)(dpiY / 96);
```

Then I set the height by multiplying the current height and width by the dpiheight and dpiwidth and now my mobile device re-size for every device

```
          datatable.width = dpiwidth * 133;      - what ever your current width is
          datatable.rowheight = (int)(dpiheight * 32);
```